# How do I populate my dictionary keys so that it gives me the value of the variable rather than the string?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to organise my data so I can view/access my chunkId's associated with each taskId. Each taskId has multiple chunkId's under it. I am thinking a dictionary, with taskId as key and chunkId as value is the way to go.

How do I populate my dictionary keys so that it gives me the value of the variable taskId, rather than the string 'taskId'?

My code:

```
result = {u'content': [{u'status': u'succeeded', u'task': [{u'id': 20170913000001}], u'id': 51924665}, {u'status': u'succeeded', u'task': [{u'id': 20170913000002}], u'id': 51924675}, {u'status': u'succeeded', u'task': [{u'id': 20170913000003}], u'id': 51924684}, {u'status': u'succeeded', u'task': [{u'id': 20170913000004}], u'id': 51924689}, {u'status': u'succeeded', u'task': [{u'id': 20170913000005}], u'id': 51924692}], u'next': None, u'message': None, u'previous': None, u'error': None}

for chunkData in result['content']:
    chunkId = chunkData['id']
    for taskData in chunkData['task']:
        taskId = taskData['id']
        dicto = dict(taskId=chunkId)
        print dicto
```

Output:

```
{'taskId': 51924665}
{'taskId': 51924675}
{'taskId': 51924684}
{'taskId': 51924689}
{'taskId': 51924692}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: It's hard to tell, since you haven't provided code capable of generating the string "taskId", nor have you provided *any* data values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the type-contructor, use a literal:

```
dicto = {taskId:chunkId}
```

Comment: Just to add a bit of info to explain things for the OP: The `dict` constructor by default uses keyword-argument names as keys in the dictionary and their respective values as the values. That's why you're getting the output you are.